# Retrieve device manufacturer without sudo

Tags: linux, hardware, non-root-user

I need to retrieve the manufacturer model of a linux device (laptop or desktop). I saw that you could use `dmidecode | grep -A3 '^System Information'` but it needs admin rights. There is any way to do it as a normal user?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of device?

Comment: A normal computer

Comment: There's no such thing as a "normal" computer. What model are you talking about? Is this a laptop? A desktop? Did you build it? Was it bought as is? Please [edit] your question and add these details and explain that you want the model number of the computer itself and not of a device. If, that is, that is indeed what you are asking.

Comment: laptop or desktop

Comment: Please _[edit]_ your question and explain. My desktop has no model. Why does yours? What kind of desktop is it? You might want to check out tools like `lshw`. I can't tell you if that will help _because you haven't explained what your hardware is_. Different machines report different data.

Comment: @terdon “whatever `dmidecode` reports as ‘Manufacturer’ under ‘System Information’” is a valid, unambiguous question.

Comment: @Gilles that returns "System manufacturer" on my system. I can get useful information about hardware vendors who built the various subsystems but it's hard to know what the OP is after.

Comment: @terdon Same for me on a home-built computer, but I have a laptop where the laptop brand is returned. The information read this way may or may not be useful, but “get the same information as `dmidecode` without requiring root access” is a well-defined question nonetheless.

Comment: For instance,  a dell laptop the model could be 'studio 1550' I've already did it for mac and Windows but linux is giving me a hard time here. If the laptop is home made,  then is not a problem to know this information